# Connecting to Database using GridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, gridview

I want to display the result in GridView and I am unable to do so. I am trying to connect my C# windows form application to the database that I created in SQL. Please tell me if there is anything else I need to put in my class to fix it. I am not getting any errors but I am its still not getting any result when  I click "See all Athletes".

```
namespace Olympics
{

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private string connectionString;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = "Data Source=ddb04;Initial Catalog=Vikram;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    public class Athlete
    {
        private string Athlete_Firstname;
        private string Athlete_Lastname;
        private string Athlete_ID;
        private string countryname;

        public Athlete()
        {

        }


        public Athlete(string firstname, string lastname, string ID, string country)
        {
            Athlete_Firstname = firstname;
            Athlete_Lastname = lastname;
            Athlete_ID = ID;
            countryname = country;
        }

        public string firestname
        {
            get { return Athlete_Firstname; }
            set
            {
                Athlete_Firstname = value;

            }
        }

        public string lastname
        {
            get { return Athlete_Lastname; }
            set
            {
                Athlete_Lastname = value;

            }
        }

        public string ID
        {
            get { return Athlete_ID; }
            set
            {
                Athlete_ID = value;

            }
        }

        public string country
        {
            get { return countryname; }
            set
            {
                countryname = value;

            }
        }

    }






    private void seeAthletesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here I access my project's connectionm string...

        //string sql = "select Athlete_Firstname, Athlete_Lastname, Athlete_ID, Country from Athlete;";

        //here I create new SQLConnection Object...

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            connection.Open();
            //here I create new SQLCommand Object.

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Athlete_Firstname, Athlete_Lastname, Athlete_ID, Country from Athlete;", connection))
            {
                //command.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                List<Athlete> atheletes = new List<Athlete>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {


                    string atheleteFirstName = reader.GetString(0);    // Athlete_Firstname string
                    string atheleteLastName = reader.GetString(1);  // Athlete_Lastname string
                    string atheleteId = reader.GetString(2); // Athlete_ID int
                    string atheleteCountry = reader.GetString(3);

                    Athlete athelete = new Athlete();
                    athelete.firestname = atheleteFirstName;
                    athelete.lastname = atheleteLastName;
                    athelete.ID = atheleteId;
                    athelete.country = atheleteCountry;

                    atheletes.Add(athelete); // List of Athelete objects populated with values from database
                }
                DataGridView atheleteDataGRidView = new DataGridView();

                atheleteDataGRidView.DataSource = atheletes;

              }
        }
    }







    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }





    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();

        string sql = "insert into Athlete (Athlete_Firstname, Athlete_Lastname, Athlete_ID, Country) values (@firstName, @lastName, @athleteId, @country);";


        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        command.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = firstName.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = lastName.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@athleteId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@athleteId"].Value = athleteId.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@country"].Value = countryName.Text;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        connection.Close();
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: it might help to display or tell us what the error is that you are getting

Comment: try looking at the following 2 links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Comment: I see you create a gridview, where did you add it to your form.  Also tag your question with ASP.Net or Winforms

Answer (score 2):

You need to write

```
atheleteDataGRidView.DataSource = atheletes;
atheleteDataGRidView.DataBind();
```

in private void seeAthletesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Oedum has said, you are accessing the ID with [`SqlDataReader.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) which throws an [`InvalidCastException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) when it can not be casted to a string. But you are commenting yourself that it's DataType is `int`.

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.

So this is probably better:

```
string atheleteId = reader.GetInt32(2).ToString(); // Athlete_ID int
```